# Windows XP considerably slowed down when creating a new thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am currently writing a game in C++ for Windows. The server counterpart creates two additional threads at the very start. One of them handles receiving new data, and the other handles movement calculation of the objects in the game. What I managed to find out is that the last thread function (called TickFunc) is the one that slows everything down. My music freezes, I can't open new tabs in my browser, everything is slow and freezes. Even if I comment everything within the TickFunc out (leaving an empty while loop that executes forever), it still freezes, but if I do not create that thread at all, it's fine. It seems as though it slows the system down regardless of the intensity of calculation performed within the TickFunc. I would really appreciate any hints concerning what may be causing this. Thank you.

Regards, 
Neob91

Comment: Are you by any chance creating that thread in a higher than normal priority?

Comment: "Leaving an empty while loop that executes forever" is the best way to slow all other threads.

Comment: No, the threads are created in the default priority, that is THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL. I even tried decreasing the priority, although it worked too slowly even if I set it to THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL.

Comment: @Alex Farber: Empty or not, it's slowing not only the threads within my program, but all threads in the operating system. Is there a way to make it stop slowing everything down?

Answer (score 2):

Put a small delay inside your infinite loop.

Comment: I do have a delay, I have a deltatime variable that tells me how much time has passed since the last execution of my code inside the loop.

`        clocks = clock();

        deltatime = double(clocks - oldclocks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        if(deltatime < 0.2)
        {
          continue;
        }`

Comment: @Neob91- Obviously the delay is not enough, if you look In your Windows Task Manager's Performance Tab I bet you will find your CPU usuage close to 100%

Comment: @Neob91:  that's not the proper way to delay.  The thread should be calling `Sleep()`.

Comment: I simply cannot afford a bigger delay, since it would affect the fluency of the game... It wouldn't look too nice if the objects were updated every half a second, would they? I hope there is another way...

Comment: Sleep() seems to work better, although I had to make slight sacrifices regarding the fluency of the game, but as they were only slight, I can live with that. Thanks!

Comment: Choices are: `YieldProcessor()` for busy-wait, `SwitchToThread()`, and `Sleep(1)`.  The operation of `Sleep(0)` varies between Windows versions.

Comment: Your initial delay wasn't really a delay, it would just continue the loop regardless of your deltatime...